# Iterating an array inside a KendoUI Template

Tags: jquery, templates, mvvm, kendo-ui

I've binding an array of objects to a Kendo template with the following code:

```
<script id="Template4" type="text/x-kendo-template">
     <div class="row">
          # for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { #
          <div class="col-md-6 " data-maxpanel="4">                   
          </div>
          # } #
     </div>       
</script>

<div class="page-detail container-fluid" id="canvas" data-bind="source: javascriptData" data-template="Template4">        
</div>

<script>
    var javascriptData = [{ Name: "First" }, { Name: "Second" }, { Name: "Third" }];
    var Model = kendo.observable({
        javascriptData: javascriptData 
    });

    kendo.bind($("#canvas"), Model);
</script>
```

The problem is that I get 3 instances of the row class div and my loop has only one item.  I can understand that is rendering the template for each element of my array.  What I want to achieve is that only one instance of the template is rendered and that I can loop over each of the records inside the template.  I'm migrating from Handlebars where the behaviour is slightly different, my loop works successfully.

I know I can create an outer array with just one record and then it will work but was wondering if there is a better way.

e.g.

```
 var javascriptData = [{ Name: "First" }, { Name: "Second" }, { Name: "Third" }];

 var jsList = [];
 jsList.push(javascriptData);

 var Model = kendo.observable({
     javascriptData: jsList
 });
```

Comment: There is no better way (and I don't see how it's a bad way in the first place). You bind a View with a ViewModel (ObservableObject), not an array of ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate into the elements of your array `javascriptData` then what you might do is define the template as:

```
<script id="Template4" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div class="col-md-6 " data-maxpanel="4">#= Name #</div>
</script>
```

and then `canvas` as:

```
<div class="page-detail container-fluid" id="canvas">
    <div class="row" data-bind="source: javascriptData" data-template="Template4">
    </div>
</div>
```

I.e. You move the outer `div` of `Template4` (the row) into the HTML. So `canvas` is bound to Model but `row` is bound to the array `javascriptData` of Model.

Check it in the following snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var javascriptData = [
    { Name: "First" }, 
    { Name: "Second" }, 
    { Name: "Third" }
  ];
  var Model = kendo.observable({
    javascriptData: javascriptData 
  });
  kendo.bind($("#canvas"), Model);
});
```

```css
.page-detail {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.col-md-6 {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.row {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>

<script id="Template4" type="text/x-kendo-template">
   <div class="col-md-6" data-maxpanel="4">#= Name #</div>
</script>

<div class="page-detail container-fluid" id="canvas">
  <div class="row" data-bind="source: javascriptData" data-template="Template4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't really work for my needs, the example I gave was simplified, I need to keep the row element inside the template.

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Maybe there is a simpler way.

Comment: I'm using the template to generate a dynamic bootstrap grid.  The grid can  be 1x1, 4x4 or can have a custom layout (e.g. 1st row 2 panels, 2nd row 5 panels).  This is why I need to have access to the array inside the template.  It might be that my approach of creating an outer array with just one element is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the best way to achieve what I want is the following:

```
var javascriptData = [{ Name: "First" }, { Name: "Second" }, { Name: "Third" }];

 var jsList = [];
 jsList.push(javascriptData);

 var Model = kendo.observable({
     javascriptData: jsList
 });
```

Essentially I am adding my array to an outer array with just one element